Matplotlib backend that avoids artifacts yet appropriate for web applications?
My chart has unwanted artifacts:

To troubleshoot I turned off the the 'agg' backend and they disappeared. Matplotlib used the default backend, I don't know which one.  I want to use a backend that doesn't create artifacts yet is appropriate for web applications.
The documentation on backends states:

still others run web application servers to dynamically serve up
graphs

Based on the sparse documentation notes regarding that use case I believed agg was the only choice.  I am building an application and know nothing about web development (yet). My question is which backend(s) are appropriate to not generate artifacts, and will be appropriate when I move to the web?
I could test the backends to see which ones don't generate artifacts but I need SO wisdom for the latter part of the question.
Per a comments:

Upgraded to matplotlib 3.9.2
Upgraded to Pillow 10.4.0
Changed to .png format image

These two upgrades had no noticeable improvements to my problem while still using .jpeg format but saving the figure as a .png did.  It may have been the combination of the updates and formatting.
Here's the code to create the chart above:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter, AutoMinorLocator
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
mpl.use('agg')
plt.style.use('dark_background')
my_figure = plt.figure(**{'dpi': 100.0,
 'edgecolor': 'black',
 'facecolor': 'black',
 'figsize': (8.0, 6.0),
 'linewidth': 1.0})
my_figure.suptitle(**{'fontsize': 'x-large',
 'fontweight': 'semibold',
 'horizontalalignment': 'center',
 't': 'Binomial Distribution Pair Plot',
 'verticalalignment': 'top'})
my_figure.supxlabel(**{'fontsize': 'large',
 'fontweight': 'normal',
 'horizontalalignment': 'center',
 't': 'Failures',
 'verticalalignment': 'bottom'})
my_figure.supylabel(**{'fontsize': 'large',
 'fontweight': 'normal',
 'horizontalalignment': 'left',
 't': 'Probability',
 'verticalalignment': 'center'})
axes_dictionary = my_figure.subplot_mosaic(mosaic=[['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay']]
                    ,gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.0, 'hspace': 0.0})
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].bar(**{'x': [0, 1, 2], 'height': [0.7778213593991469, 0.19641953520180488, 0.02380842850930969], 'label': 'individual probability', 'color': 'C0', 'zorder': 10})
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].bar(**{'x': [0, 1, 2], 'height': [0.7778213593991469, 0.9742408946009518, 0.9980493231102614], 'label': 'cumulative probability', 'color': 'C1', 'zorder': 5, 'alpha': 0.2})
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].set_xticks(ticks=[0, 1, 2], labels=[0, 1, 2])
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].set_ylim(ymax=1.0)
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
axes_dictionary['binomial_w_cumulative_overlay'].yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(xmax=1.0))
my_figure.savefig('test_figure.jpg')
Image.open('test_figure.jpg').show()
plt.show()


I don't get the artifacts when running your code (mpl 3.9.2, pillow 10.4.0)

Interesting, I checked and I'm using Matplotlib 3.8.0, Pillow 10.0.1.  Will upgrade and see if the issue persists.

@Stef, tried your suggestion but the issue persists, updated question to include note this route was tried.  Thank you.

Try saving as png instead of jpeg.  jpeg is better for highly variable images like photographs.  png is better for flat images like this.

Save as png.  Also use higher dpi.

@RuthC, png was the answer, post as answer and I will accept.  @Jody Kymak, you also suggested the same, dpi was a non-issue in this case.
